# Pulling alias from Joomla content database

Tags: php, sql, joomla, alias

So I am trying to pull the alias of the current article (the article that the code is placed in) from the database.

I have a PHP snippet to pull the alias of the category of the current article:

```
<?php // Get category alias
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();            

$option   = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view   = JRequest::getCmd('view');

$temp   = JRequest::getString('id');
$temp   = explode(':', $temp);
$id   = $temp[0];

/* Checking if we are making up an article page */
if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'article' && $id)
{            
   /* Trying to get CATEGORY alias from DB */
   $db->setQuery('SELECT cat.alias FROM #__categories cat RIGHT JOIN #__content cont ON cat.id = cont.catid WHERE cont.id='.$id);   
   $category_alias = $db->loadResult();           
}
?>
```

I then use the variable `$category_alias` as a PHP argument for an iframe. All of this is embedded into the article using the plugin DirectPHP.

My problem is to rewrite this code to pull the alias of the current ARTICLE instead of the current CATEGORY.

I have read the Joomla documentation but I am completely stumped on what table/columns I need to use to get the alias of the articles.

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a lot of legacy code:

- JRequest should not be used to access request parameters.
- Objects are assigned per reference, so don't use the reference operator (&) for objects.
- Use the query interface.
- Pretect your code against SQL injection.

The alias value you're looking for is stored in the content table together with the article.

Your code - together with the suggested corrections - will then look like this:

```
<?php
$input  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$option = $input->getCmd('option');
$view   = $input->getCmd('view');
$id     = array_shift(explode(':', $input->getString('id', 0)));

if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'article' && !empty($id))
{
    $db    = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('alias')
        ->from('#__content')
        ->where('id=' . (int)$id);
    $db->setQuery($query);   
    $article_alias = $db->loadResult();           
}
```

Your article's alias will then be accessible through `$article_alias` (but only within the `if` block!).

Comment: Thank you very much! The only thing I wonder about with this one is that you say that the alias (`$article_alias`) will only be accesible within the `if` block. Will I have to transfer it to a variable outside of the `if` block?

Comment: Outside the `if` block you cannot be sure that the variable has got assigned a value, so you can only rely on it inside the block. If you want to use it after the block, you have to assign a default value to it before the `if` statement.